# Use Arduino Usb2Serial converter with Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, arduino, serial-port, microcontroller

I'm absolutely stuck here. I want to program a micro controller (Arduino Pro Mini and later native AtTiny85) from my mac using Arduino IDE 1.6.12. I need to use a usb to serial converter as the micro controllers in question do not have a usb interface. I purchased an Arduino usb2serial converter and attached it to my mac, but unfortunately the serial interface does not show up in the Arduino IDE :-(

From searching the web, it seems like the problem is that no serial driver can be loaded. So first I made sure, that the rootless configuration is put in a state, that necessary kext extensions can be loaded:

```
csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

Next I tried various hints rom the web saying I needed to install FTDI Support - so I got myself libusb, FTDIUSBSerialDriver and DFU-Programmer and installed everything - which worked flawlessly.

*Nevertheless*, my serial connection is not shown in the IDE and I can't pull any board information. Has anyone any idea???

I attach some links, so people may be able to follow my path  of thinking:

Micro Controller: [Arduino Pro Mini](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini)

USB2Serial Converter: [USB2Serial converter at exp tech](http://www.exp-tech.de/arduino-usb-2-serial-converter)